# ChromeCustomTab - Fullscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to run the Chrome-CustomTab automatic in full screen mode?

I think I've tried everything, I'll be grateful for any help.

Greetings

HumanINC

Comment: And what exactly have you tried so far? Could you please edit your question and add it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to run a Chrome Custom Tab full-screen.

The nearest equivalent feature is a Trusted Web Activity: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/using-twa